# I am not able connect Node.js project with Mamp dadabase

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mamp

Hi I am using below code to connect with Mamp data base "http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/server_databases.php?server=1" but not able to do it getting below error

code :-

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'nodejs.login',
})

db.connect((error) =>{
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    }else {
        console.log("Mysql Connected....")
    }
    
})
```

error:-

```
server startwd on Port 5003
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/ruchir/Documents/Assesment_Node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/ruchir/Documents/Assesment_Node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/ruchir/Documents/Assesment_Node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ruchir/Documents/Assesment_Node/app.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve it.i have check and find my Mamp server was running on 8889
so i have added one more variable in connetion  `port: '8889'` at it works.

Answer (score 1):

your problem might be in the connection parameters, you are setting your `password: 'root'`.
In my experience the password usually is left blank: `password: ''`.

Comment: that's not a problem error is coming with or without password

Comment: @jugal have you checked that your MySQL Mamp server is running in `localhost:3306`? You could check if anything else is trying to run on that port